# Require forward-dns somehost.com returns Unknown Authz provide

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I've been trying to set up:
 Require forward-dns somehostname.mydns.rocks 
to prevent access to a sandbox except for devs.  I can't use IPs, since they aren't static, and in theory the forward-dns directive is exactly what I need (used along with a dnynamic dns hostnames of the client machines)

But when I try to use the "Require forward-dns somehostname.mydns.rocks" directive, apache spits out:
 .htaccess: Unknown Authz provider: forward-dns"

I feel like Im missing some required step that isn't clear in the docs to get forward-dns working (apache 2.4.6 on centos 7)

P.S. the Require host directive works, and since the host directive first does a reverse dns, followed by a forward dnslookup on the results of the reverse dns lookup, I wold expect forward-dns to just work.

What step could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html
says:

> The forward-dns provider was addded in 2.4.19

Your apache Version 2.4.6 is too old. Try updating to a newer version.